# how to refer two or more angular model properties in the html directives like [title] = "model.prop1 - model.prop2"

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular9

Assume i have my component with a model class User with Username, Nickname, First name, Last name.

```
export class User
{
    Username: string;
    Nickname: string;
    Firstname: string;
    Lastname: string;
    Email: string;
}
```

I want the html to render something like,

```
<div [title]="user.Username - user.Nickname">
...
</div>
```

I tried the above but it wont work. If it were to be a value or inner Html i know how to use it but i wanted something like on the tool-tip or title property.

How do i go about doing that without having to create another property in my model class? At the moment, i want to show a tool-tip combining of two model props. What am i missing here to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add brackets and string concatenation. Try the following

```html
<div [title]="(user.Username) + '-' + (user.Nickname)">
...
</div>
```

Alternatively you could also use data interpolation

```html
<div title="{{user.Username}}-{{user.Nickname}}">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! both works as charm. The mistake i was doing around was having the second alternate option with the model directive syntax, using the square brackets.

Comment: One more info, while directives also use the same binding syntax, it'd be clearer if the expression `[target]="expression"` is referred to as [data-binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) instead of model directive syntax.